# Computer frequently shutting down (gpu dying?)

Tags: graphics-card

Starting a couple of days ago, my computer has been randomly rebooting at periodic intervals. I don't get "Windows is shutting down", a plain black screen, blue screen, or something like that. Instead, my screens freeze for a couple of seconds, I get this flat, buzzing noise from my headphones, and then the computer reboots. Here's a picture I managed to snap of the screen freezing:

[image]

The top monitor is hooked into the onboard graphics card, but the bottom two are plugged into the dedicated one. The left one always goes black, but the primary one (one right of the big one) gets vertical bars. It's hard to see because I had to be quick with the camera, but the main monitor's screen isn't a solid color. It doesn't have to be green either -- most of the time it looks greyish. The computer does this seemingly at random -- it could happen while I'm playing a game, while I'm opening a webpage (no hardware-intensive programs running in the background), or while the computer is just idling. The closest interval I've seen it happen at is probably within an hour, but sometimes it can go for a whole day with no issue.

The dedicated card is an AMD Radeon 7800 with 2GB of VRAM, and a year after I bought the computer and the GPU it died (same thing that's happening to it now (only happened once though -- no instances prior to it dying) but it didn't reboot). I took it to the guy I bought the computer from (local shop) and he said he "fixed" it -- it was repaired and working fine December 22nd of last year. My worry is that he didn't really fix it (even though he charged me 1/2 the price of buying a replacement copy of my graphics card), and that my graphics card is having issues again and may be on the verge of dying a second time.

Just to confirm though, this sounds like a problem with the graphics card, right? I just did a clean install from Windows 7 to 10, so I wouldn't think it's a software issue. How safe is it to use that computer at all (in terms of killing my graphics card) in the event I need to use it? I won't be able to take it to a shop or anything until next Thursday, so I'm wondering if it'll be fine to use it until then. Also, can graphics cards really even be fixed to where they're in tip-top shape in the first place? I'm debating whether I should get a new one or not.

Comment: Sounds a lot like GPU symptoms (especially if someone has claimed to "fix" it... Did he say how? Installed new drivers? Reseated it? Reballed it? Either way, I don't believe there would be a reliable way to fix a graphics card.) Does your machine have onboard graphics you could test with?

Comment: He told me the reason it died was because it was overclocked (which is odd because I never overclocked it), and said that he fixed it with a graphics board repair machine and "reset the voltage on the card so it can't overclock. Should last 3 or 4 years" When I was there in person he told me he was just going to put it into the oven, but he texted me what I just posted as he told me how large the bill was. Yes, I have an on-board, I'll remove the dedicated and run it with just the on-board and see if it still has problems.

Comment: I had a little giggle at that if I'm honest. Overclocking GPUs is usually done through software (although firmware versions do exist), not sure why he'd need a "graphics board repair machine"... Would be interesting if you can post a screenshot from [GPU-Z](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/) to see what frequencies and voltages it's running at (Both the Graphics Card and Sensors tab). Either way, if it's running at stock frequencies and voltages and not currently overclocked, it sounds like it's failing. Testing on on-board should hopefully give a better idea.

Comment: Graphics card tab: http://gpuz.techpowerup.com/16/01/31/dpu.png Sensors tab: http://gpuz.techpowerup.com/16/01/31/ffw.png

Comment: That is your Onboard GPU I'm guessing - I meant with your discreet card, but it's not too important at the moment (if you haven't already removed it, use the dropdown at the bottom). See if you can replicate the issues without it :)

Comment: Oh, oops -- didn't notice the dropdown at the bottom. Graphics Card: http://gpuz.techpowerup.com/16/01/31/mwp.png Sensors: http://gpuz.techpowerup.com/16/01/31/n8e.png

Comment: Yeah that looks stock, I can't say for certain but it looks like a 7870 stock is around 1000Mhz Core and 1200Mhz Memory clock - not sure on your exact model but your core is a little lower, which is fine. Voltage looks low at the time of the screenshot, but I can see it spikes up to what I'm guessing is the stock voltage too. I'd take out the card and use just the onboard for a while.

Comment: check your power supply, sometimes a failed power source will cause the same problem; check every wire that's goes to your mother board with multi-meter, you can find the right value on your power supply for each color

Comment: It is worth noting in your 'Sensors' tab, the 12V is fairly unstable. Whether thats the reading of the card, or the GPU, it's hard to say. If you have a multimeter as @narzan says, check the Yellow to Black to be sure it's 12v.